# Modular exponentiation pattern question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I once found this problem

Find the form of all $n$ such that
$$3 \cdot 5^{2n+1}+2^{3n+1}=0 \pmod{17}$$
I started by writing the residues $\pmod{17}$ of $3 \cdot 5^{k}$ and $2^k$
$$3 \cdot 5^1+2 \equiv 0\pmod{17},\,2^1+15\equiv 0 \pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^2+10\equiv 0\pmod{17},\,2^2+13\equiv 0 \pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^3+16\equiv 0\pmod{17},\,2^3+9\equiv  0 \pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^4+12\equiv 0\pmod{17},\,2^4+1\equiv  0 \pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^5+9 \equiv 0\pmod{17},\,2^5+2\equiv  0 \pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^6+11\equiv 0\pmod{17},\,2^6+4\equiv  0 \pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^7+4 \equiv 0\pmod{17},\,2^7+8\equiv  0 \pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^8+3 \equiv 0\pmod{17},\,2^8+16\equiv 0 \pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^9+15\equiv 0\pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^{10}+7\equiv  0\pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^{11}+1\equiv  0\pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^{12}+5\equiv  0\pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^{13}+8\equiv  0\pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^{14}+6\equiv  0\pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^{15}+13\equiv 0\pmod{17}$$
$$3 \cdot 5^{16}+14\equiv 0\pmod{17}$$
And then when I paired the residues so that they "completed the $17$" I found the relation that
$$3 \cdot 5^{16m+6k+1}+2^{8n+k+1}=0\pmod{17}$$
for all $m,n,k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$

Then solving diophantically with the exponents is easy, but my question in essence is: Why does this happens? I don't refer to $m$ or $n$, but to $k$. It is trivial that the residues repeat after some period, but i can't find a reason for the $k,6k$. I don't think that $3,5,2$ are the only numbers at all. And: Is there a general forula/algorithm for this? Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any integer $n$,
$$\begin{align*}
3\cdot 5^{2n+1}+2^{3n+1}&\equiv 0\bmod 17\\[0.1in]
15\cdot 5^{2n}+2^{3n+1}&\equiv 0\bmod 17\\[0.1in]
15\cdot 5^{2n}&\equiv -2\cdot 2^{3n}\bmod 17\\[0.1in]
15\cdot 5^{2n}\cdot 9^{2n}&\equiv -2\cdot2^{3n}\cdot 9^{2n}\bmod 17 & \text{(we do this because $9\equiv 2^{-1}\bmod 17$)}\\[0.1in]
15\cdot (45)^{2n}&\equiv -2\cdot2^n\bmod 17\\[0.1in]
15\cdot 11^{2n}&\equiv -2\cdot2^n\bmod 17\\[0.1in]
15\cdot 11^{2n}\cdot 14^n&\equiv -2\cdot2^n\cdot 14^n\bmod 17& \text{(we do this because $14\equiv 11^{-1}\bmod 17$)}\\[0.1in]
15\cdot 11^n&\equiv -2\cdot11^n\bmod 17\\[0.1in]
17\cdot 11^n&\equiv 0\bmod 17\\[0.1in]
0\cdot 11^n&\equiv 0\bmod 17
\end{align*}$$
which is always true.

Comment: I did the problem the all-naive-way, because I am just starting to learn number theory, and I didn't knew how to solve the equation. After googling, I found that this is about multiplicative inverses, thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 4):

$$3\cdot5^{2n+1}+2^{3n+1}=15\cdot25^n+2\cdot 8^n$$

$$\text{ As }25\equiv 8\pmod {17}\implies 25^n\equiv 8^n\pmod{17},$$

$$15\cdot25^n+2\cdot 8^n\equiv 15\cdot 8^n+2\cdot 8^n=8^n(15+2)\equiv0\pmod{17}$$

**Generalization(s)**:

$1:$

If $m$ divides $a-b$ and $c+d,m$ will divide $c(a-b)+b(c+d)=bd-ca$

Putting $c=15,d=2,a=25^n,b=8^n\implies 15\cdot25^n+2\cdot 8^n=15(25^n-8^n)+(15+2)8^n$

Putting $c=2,d=15,a=8^n,b=25^n\implies 15\cdot25^n+2\cdot 8^n=2(8^n-25^n)+(2+15)25^n$

$2:$ $$a\cdot c^n+(m\cdot d -a)(m\cdot e+c)^n\equiv a\cdot c^n-a\cdot (m\cdot e+c)^n\equiv a\cdot c^n-a\cdot c^n\equiv0\pmod m$$

for any integer $m,a,b,c,d,e,n $

Here $m=17, a=15, m\cdot d -a=2\implies d=1;$

$c=25, m\cdot e+c=8\implies e=-1$